# Python turning series of series into DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Having created a pandas DataFrame from a groupby and apply method, I am now trying to extract a subset of this DataFrame into a new DataFrame. I have created a function which extracts the data but I need but it is returning the data as a series of series. Unfortunately, I cant just directly turn these series into DataFrames using dicts, as each series is a row, not a column. I have posted the code for the function. Below thanks a lot for any help you may have.

```
    def sel(df):
      for i in range(len(df)):
        if len(df.iloc[i][4].split()) == 3:
          return df.iloc[i][1:4]
```

I am then running this function and assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps `pd.concat(series.tolist())`  might help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to take the columns 1 through 3 from the rows that have three words in the column 4, correct? You can do this without any loops.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1,  2,  3, "a b c"],
                   [4, 5,  6,  7, "a b"],
                   [8, 9, 10, 11, "d e f"]])
df[df[4].str.split().str.len() == 3].iloc[:, 1:4]
#   1   2   3
#0  1   2   3
#2  9  10  11
```

Comment: DyZ, thank you very much for your solution: If you have a chance could you explain to me why, Final = GroupMin[len(GroupMin['Acquiring Institution'].split()) == 3].iloc[:, 1:4], returned the following ''' 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' '''. Which I had tried earlier. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Because, as the error message says, a Series does not have that function. I do not know how to explain better. By design?

Comment: OK, gotcha. Thanks, so the .str allows you to apply a string method to a series. Thanks, again.